# Ext JS how to set vtype dynamically

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a usecase where I will come to know about validation type after the textfield is rendered. I would like to know if there is any way to set 'vtype' dynamically on the textfield. I tried the below options, but none of them worked.

1) Ext.getCmp('textfieldId').vtype = 'email'

2) Ext.getCmp('textfieldId').vtype = 'email'
   Ext.getCmp('textfieldId').doComponentLayout();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ExtJs - Change Textfield VType dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519233/extjs-change-textfield-vtype-dynamically)  
Even though this question was asked about a month earlier, I've marked this one as a duplicate because the other on has more elaborated answers

Answer (score 0):

My bad,I was checking the wrong field in UI. The first option did work. Just setting the vtype is enough.