# ExtJs - Change Textfield VType dynamically

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

A rather straightforward question.  No answer found anywhere.

Using ExtJs 4.2

I have two custom VTypes, and one textfield.  I want to change that textfield's vtype when the user clicks a radio button.

I know that the text field has already been created so doing:

```
textfield.vtype = 'otherType';
```

won't do it for me.  Neither will:

```
Ext.apply(textField,{vtype:'otherType'});
```

So the obvious stuff is out.  Now I'm toying with destroying and re-creating it, but (if it even works) that seems like overkill.

Comment: You'll need to destroy and re-create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Ext.apply worked for me, fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/4d4

Hope this helps..

Comment: Its hard to argue with a working fiddle.  I will accept this answer because it is correct for the question asked.  I must be doing something somewhere else thats causing me heartburn.  Thanks for the time and help.

Comment: Changing vtype had issues when it was set as config during text field creation. Instead setting initial vtype using Ext.Apply worked (in my case)

Comment: I observed that this method is working for validation, but it's not changing the mask. So after changing the vtype, you'll be able to type characters according to the mask of the previous vtype.

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek, true, the mask is not getting changed. Pls let know if you find any workaround.

Comment: I found one. I wrote an answer about it

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are not taking into account that the maskRe needs to change as well. Why? If you just apply a new vtype the validation will be according to the new vtype, but the characters you're allowed to type does not change along with the new vtype.

This is the full solution.

```
textfield.vtype = 'otherType';
textfield.validate();
textfield.maskRe = Ext.form.field.VTypes[textfield.vtype + 'Mask'];
```

If you want to know why, look at the source at how maskRe is set initially: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Text2.html#Ext-form-field-Text-method-initEvents

Here's an override that allows you to call setVType on any textfield.

```
Ext.define('Ext.overrides.form.field.Text', {
    override: 'Ext.form.field.Text',

    /**
     * Changes the vtype, adjusts the maskRe
     * and revalidates unless withValidate is false.
     */
    setVType: function(newVtype, withValidate) {
        var me = this;

        me.vtype = newVtype;
        if (withValidate !== false) {
            me.validate();
        }
        me.maskRe = Ext.form.field.VTypes[me.vtype + 'Mask'];    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Ext.apply and validate() worked for me, fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/10mp

Use for validation without clear field:

```
Ext.apply(textField,{vtype:'otherType'});
textField.validate();
```